# How to refer to the application context from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I'm using the usual technique of extending Application in order to store global constants.

So within my activities, I can simply do (in oncreate()):

```
W = (WcmApplication) getApplicationContext();
```

However, this doesn't work for broadcast receivers:

```
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type MyReceiver
```

So, thinking I was being clever, I tried to do:

```
 W = (WcmApplication) context;
```

... but that throws an error at runtime saying my broadcast receiver is not allowed to access that context

Not giving up, I try this:

```
W = (WcmApplication) Context.getApplicationContext();
```

... no dice

So I ended up having to do:

```
W = (WcmApplication)context.getApplicationContext() ;
```

... and that works nicely, however I have no idea why.

Can someone explain why one works and not the others?

Thank you!

Comment: what you want with that context?

Comment: Well without the context I cannot cast to my custom application as declared in the manifest.

Comment: I never met this requirement to cast application as declared in manifest.It will be easy to answer your question if you make it more specific

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/821423

Answer (score 2):

`Activity` inherits `Context`, hence you have direct access to the `getApplicationContext()` method defined on `Context`. `BroadcastReceiver` on the other hand does not inherit from `Context`, which is why it has to receive the `context` from outside, when invoked to process a broadcast.

In general, the direct `Context` you have access to from any component (`Activity`, `Service`, `ContentProvider`, or `BroadcastReceiver`) is a specific for that particular component and defines the *context* of execution of that component (hence the name :-)). The application context on the other hand defines a more generic *context* of execution for the whole application. So, the application *context* is a broader than the component *context*.

Keep also in mind that it is possible to have more than these two *contexts* (application and component) chained up at any point in time. You could walk the chain of contexts partially by attempting to cast each node (starting from the component *context*) to `ContextWrapper` and if successful use `getBaseContext`. However, this is a rare advanced scenario, and most times there are only two *contexts* in the chain that you care - the immediate component one, and the overarching application one.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a comprehensive solution (*finally thanks to @Franci Penov's post*)

This is a static method on my custom Application subclass.

```
public static MyApp get( @NonNull final Context context )
{
    if( s_instance != null )
    {
        return s_instance;
    }
    else
    {
        if( context instanceof Activity )
        {
            final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            s_instance = (MyApp) activity.getApplication();
        }
        else if( context instanceof Service )
        {
            final Service service = (Service) context;
            s_instance = (MyApp) service.getApplication();
        }
        else if( context instanceof ContextWrapper )
        {
            final ContextWrapper contextWrapper = (ContextWrapper) context;
            s_instance = (MyApp) contextWrapper.getBaseContext().getApplicationContext();
        }
        else
        {
            s_instance = (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext();
        }

        return s_instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not application context:

```
(WcmApplication) context;
```

but rather context of an action. This is why you need to call:

```
(WcmApplication)context.getApplicationContext() ;
```